# AttributeError: /usr/lib/ogdi/libgdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALVersionInfo

Tags: python-2.7, postgis, geodjango

I have setup the database using geodjango documentation and when I am doing

```
python manage.py sqlall world
```

I am getting this error:

```
OSError: /home/nishant-un/local/lib/libgdal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And when I

```
locate libgdal.so
```

I found it in:

```
/usr/lib/ogdi/libgdal.so
```

So I changed the GeoDjango Settings:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/home/nishant-un/local/lib/libgdal.so'
```

to

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/lib/ogdi/libgdal.so'
```

Then When I do `python manage.py sqlall world` again:

I get the error as:

```
AttributeError: /usr/lib/ogdi/libgdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALVersionInfo
```

Does anyone has Any idea why am I getting this error .. ?

`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the answer, I Uncommented the two lines in the `settings.py` and it started working.

```
# GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/lib/libgeos_c.so.1'

# GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/lib/ogdi/libgdal.so'
```