# Problems with installation GeoDjango in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, django, postgresql, gis, geodjango

I have few problems with installation GeoDjango. I tried install SpatiaLite for using it with SQLite and PostGIS for PostgreSQL with this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#spatial-database but no working results. 
Actually I have

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    ...
    }
}

GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/lib/libgeos_c.so.1'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/lib/ogdi/libgdal.so'
```

in my `settings.py` and I get error:

```
AttributeError: /usr/lib/ogdi/libgdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALVersionInfo
```

I have installed `gdal` package and path to these libraries are correct. I did't find anything else what can I do to get ride with this error. What is problem with this error? Should I install some more packages? I use Python2.7 and Django 1.8

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/21513980/2354734 commenting the `GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH` and `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` does the trick.

Comment: When I comment these lines I get `OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name`

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72530/gdal-loads-in-python-but-not-ipython-linux seems to have a similar problem, which version of sqlite do you use? (That was the problem there)

Comment: I use SQLite3. But in actual configuration, shouldn't it use PostgreeSQL database?

Comment: Tried with: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip no efects. The same errors with MySQL database. Any suggestions what else?

Comment: Finally done. I used `django-leaflet` and `django-geojson`, deleted `gdal`, `gis`, `geos` and some unnecessary packages. Now it's storred in simple JSONField but it's works