# AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64 While installing in Docker

Tags: c++, django, postgresql, docker, gdal

**Getting error while installing GeoDjango on docker with postgres db.**

I'm completely new to docker and i'm setting up my project on docker. I don't know, is this error is regarding django or postgres.

Found this error

> AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol:
>   OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64 While installing in Docker

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
        postgres:
                restart: always
                image: postgres:alpine
                volumes:
                        - ./postgres_gis/gis_db:/home/dev/gis_db.sql
                environment:
                        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
                        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Dev@mishra123
                        POSTGRES_DB: gis_db
                expose:
                        - "5432"
        web:
                build: ./HomePage
                restart: always
                expose:
                        - "8000"
                volumes:
                        - ./HomePage:/home/dev/app/HomePage
                depends_on:
                        - postgres
                environment:
                        - DEBUG=1
```

**web/Dockerfile**

```
from python:3.6.2-slim
RUN groupadd dev && useradd -m -g dev -s /bin/bash dev
RUN echo "dev ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN mkdir -p /home/dev/app/HomePage
RUN chown -R dev:dev /home/dev/app
RUN chmod -R +x+r+w /home/dev/app
WORKDIR /home/dev/app/HomePage
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
COPY requirements.txt /home/dev/app/HomePage
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
USER dev
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

web/docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

**docker-compose ps :**

```
root@BlackCat:/home/dev/Project-EX/django-PR# docker-compose up      
Starting django-pr_postgres_1 ... done
Starting django-pr_web_1      ... done
Attaching to django-pr_postgres_1, django-pr_web_1
postgres_1  | 2019-12-12 16:34:43.907 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2019-12-12 16:34:43.908 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2019-12-12 16:34:44.099 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2019-12-12 16:34:44.672 UTC [18] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-12-11 18:45:45 UTC
postgres_1  | 2019-12-12 16:34:44.912 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1       |   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
web_1       |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
web_1       |     utility.execute()
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
web_1       |     django.setup()
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
web_1       |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
web_1       |     app_config.import_models()
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
web_1       |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
web_1       |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, 
web_1       |     func = self.__getitem__(name)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
web_1       |     func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
web_1       | AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64
web_1       | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

Comment: Maybe you need to also `apt-get install libgdal-dev`?

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Please check it

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513980/attributeerror-usr-lib-ogdi-libgdal-so-undefined-symbol-gdalversioninfo?

Comment: No, It's not working

Comment: This probably won't solve it, but you also need to remove the `CMD` from your `Dockerfile` and rebuild -- you can only have either `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`, but not both

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that your version of GDAL is too old. Your `Dockerfile` is built on `python:3.6.2-slim`, which is based off Debian Jessie, and installs `gdal` version `1.10.1`.  The `OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64` variable was [introduced in v. 2.0.0](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/e5371b782e78f417cf0c9e551e381434ef1c9b73)

According to the [GDAL package page](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=gdal) at debian.org, you need a newer version of Debian (stretch, buster, bullseye will all work).  As such, I would recommend that you change your `Dockerfile` to use `python:3.8.0-slim-buster` or newer.  Please check the [hub.docker.com python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) page for more information

Also, as mentioned in the comments, your `Dockerfile` should only have one of `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`, but not both.  Since your `entrypoint.sh` does what `CMD` does and more, I'd just remove `CMD` and stick with `ENTRYPOINT`

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, it also solved my problem.

Comment: Any solution using the Jessie runtime? Please? I am deploying in google cloud and their images are based upon Jessie.

Comment: If you must use Jessie, I think you need to compile `gdal` on your own (https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, without Docker. I fixed it with this:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

More info: https://developers.planet.com/planetschool/gdal-qgis-installation-setup/